# How to display both events and tasks on fullcalendar?

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

I want to show both events and tasks on the calendar but don't know how to do this? Currently, I'm displaying only events on the calendar but don't know how to display both at a time.

For now, it's only displaying events but I want to show tasks as well on the calendar.

Ajax for Fetching Events & Tasks:

```
  function fetchEventAndRenderCalendar(){
          var events = [];
          var tasks = []; //step 2
          $.ajax({
            url:'events',
            type: "GET",
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data.events);
              console.log(data.tasks);
              $.each(data.events, function(index, val){ //step 3
                  //alert(data);
                  events.push({
                    id: val.id,
                    title: val.name,
                    start: val.start_date,
                    end: val.end_date,
                    start_time: val.start_time,
                    end_time: val.end_time,
                    location:val.location,
                    description: val.description,
                    calendar_type: val.calendar_type,
                    timezone: val.timezone,
                    allDay: val.isFullDay
                  });
              });
              $.each(data.tasks, function(index, val){ //steps 4
                  //alert(data);
                  tasks.push({
                    id: val.id,
                    title: val.name,
                    start: val.due_date,
                    assigned_to: val.assigned_to,
                    description: val.description,
                    calendar_type: val.calendar_type,
                    link_to: val.link_to
                  });
              })
              //$this.$calendarObj.fullCalendar('renderEvents', events);
              //console.log(tasks);
               generateCalendar(events);
            },
            error : function(error){
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
```

GenrateCalendar Function:

```
function generateCalendar(events){
          $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
              //slotDuration: '00:15:00', /* If we want to split day time each 15minutes */
              //minTime: '00:00:00',
              //maxTime: '24:00:00',

              defaultView: 'month',
              handleWindowResize: true,
              //defaultDate: new Date(),
              timeFormat:'h(:mm)a',
              height:1000,//$(window).height()-300  ,           //
              header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
              },
              events: events,
              // tasks: events,
              eventColor: '#039cfd',
              editable: true,
              droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
              eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
              selectable: true,
              drop: function(date) { $this.onDrop($(this), date); },
              select: function (start, end, allDay) { $this.onSelect(start, end, allDay); },
              eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { $this.onEventClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view); }

          });
        }
```

what's the best possible option ?

Comment: either a) put all the events and tasks into the same array and give that to fullCalendar, or b) use the "eventSources" feature of fullCalendar to define two separate event feeds.

Comment: If I stick with a) how am I going to loop over it to get their values ?

Comment: In the second .each loop (inside the "success" function) just replace `tasks.push` with `events.push`. Then all the data ends up inside the same array.

Comment: Thanks Adyson! It works.

Comment: with that being done, how should i write **eventClick** function so that if i click on an event,  it should open its edit modal and for tasks, it's own corresponding modal ?

Comment: maybe add a custom property like `type: "event"` and `type: "task"` (respectively) to your objects when you create them. Then in eventClick you can look at this property for the clicked event, and decide what to do.